# How can i do two subtitle using react native FlatList, ListItem?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

I do list in my react native app. 
I have this:

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.items}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <ListItem
            title={`${item.object.street_number}${item.object.apt_number?'/'+item.object.apt_number:''} ${item.object.street_name} ${item.object.city}`}
            subtitle={`Payment: ${item.data[0].is_paid ? 'Paid' : 'No Paid'}`}
        />
    )}
/>
```

Can i do the second subtitle or do line break?

Comment: There is no `ListItem` in react native. Is that a library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is totally up to you to define your own renderItem() function

```
renderItem({item}) {

  const time = `${item.time}`;
  const place = `${item.place}`;
  const temp = css.addDegreesToEnd(item.currentTemp);
  const {iconName, iconFont, iconColor} = item.icon;

  let actualRowComponent =
    <View style={css.home_screen_list.row}>
      <View style={...}>
        <Text style={...}>{time}</Text>   //First text
        <Text style={...}>{place}</Text> //Second
      </View>
      <Icon color={iconColor} size={...} name={iconName}  //Others
            type={iconFont}/>
      <Text style={...}>{temp}</Text>
    </View>;

  ...

}
```

Even complex layouts are also possible, not to mention two text rows, for instance:

[image]